# How to mock a method from a functional component in React using jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

```
import React from 'react';

export const HomePage = () => {

     const fetchResults = () => {
          return new Promise((resolve) => {
            Adaptor.fetch();
         });
        }
    const [initialState, dispatch] = useTableState();
    if (initialState.fetchNew) {
        let promise = fetchResults().then((res) => {
            //dispatch
        })
        throw promise;
    }
    return <Content />
}
```

I need to mock the **fetchResults** method in the homepage component mentioned above in such a way that it should return a resolved promise having mock json result. Tried many approaches but nothing is working out

one of the approach tried was:-

```
 jest.mock("../components/homePage", () => {
            return {
                fetchResults: () => {
                return  Promise.resolve({data: [{value: 'test'}]});
              },
            };
          });
```

Can someone help me to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to return the default.
Also you can set the mocked data directly.

```
jest.mock("../components/homePage", () => {
  return {
    default: () => {
      return <Content {...mockedData} />;
    },
  };
});
```

Comment: Where are you mocking the function here? I need to mock the fetch method with a mock result sothat it won't invoke the server API in the component.